# Converting dimension attribute to measure

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have to multiply some measure by value from dimension attribute.

I'm trying to make regular measure from this attribute and then i would can multiply

my code is:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Formulaa]
 AS 
(
   [DIM RESOURCE].[Formula].Member_Value 
),
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'x'  ;  

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Formulaaa]
 AS 
(
   [Measures].[Formulaa] * [Measures].[Line Quantity In]     
),
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'x'  ;
```

and it's working until i have in my browser (or query)  `[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula]` attribute

But, when i remove it - i'm getting in `[Measures].[Formulaa]` the `All` value

So my question is: What i should do to avoid browsing this attribute?

Comment: you have two measures with the same name `Formulaa` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should know that in absence of a scope, it is the `[ALL]` member which a hierarchy is defaulted to. So, for your measure `[Measures].[Formulaa]` to work, you should be having a member from `[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula]` in your slicer or one of the axes.

Secondly, could you try replacing

`[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula].Member_Value`

with

`[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula].CURRENTMEMBER.Member_Value`? The `CURRENTMEMBER` picks up the member in `[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula]` hierarchy which is currently in scope.

**EDIT** Keep the definitions as it is, but change the query as below:

```
SELECT 
    { 
        [Measures].[Line Quantity In], 
        [Measures].[Quantity In], 
        [Measures].[Formulaa] 
    } ON COLUMNS, 

    { 
        [DIM RESOURCE].[Formula].CHILDREN
    } ON ROWS 

FROM [CMR]
```

There are two ways of setting scope. You can either slice the cube by setting a member on the filter axis/sub-select OR you can specify the members on either of the axes. But you can't have unrelated in different axis and at the same time expect the measure value to change. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Adding Currentmember i am getting the same result.

I need this member value without having it in my slicer, it's possible?

Comment: Paste the query you are using, please.

Comment: SELECT { [Measures].[Line Quantity In], [Measures].[Quantity In], [Measures].[Formulaa] } ON COLUMNS, { ([DIM RESOURCE].[Production Lines].[Production Line Desc].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS FROM [CMR]

Comment: You have `[DIM RESOURCE].[Formula]` in the definition of the member while nothing from the same hierarchy on the axis. That wont work. Instead you can try the "edit" which I have above.